# Does iPad 9.7 2019 have a different Touch ID?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, touch-id

I have 3 devices equipped with Touch ID:

- iPhone 7 2016
- iPad 9.7 2019
- MacBook Pro 13 2019

The Touch ID on my phone works maybe 10% of the time with my sweaty hands, while I have almost 100% success rate with iPad and MBP.

Are different sensors used on these devices?

Comment: I'd try clearing down the TouchID & set it up afresh. I've seen people manage to [without knowing they shouldn't] use 2 different fingers to set up one TouchID & it remarkably still works, so I'd blame the stored data.

Comment: I've had the same results with my iPad 5th gen and iPhone 5s. I also found that my iPhone works more often when I have cold hands.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different generations of Touch ID hardware in Apple devices. The 2nd gen Touch ID hardware is widely regarded as being much faster — nearly instantaneous — compared to the 1st gen Touch ID.

Regarding the specific Apple products in your question: the 2019 iPad uses 1st gen Touch ID and the MacBook and iPhone 7 both use 2nd gen.

See this [Wikipedia article on Touch ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_ID) for more details.

As of this writing, the breakdown between products with 1st gen vs 2nd gen Touch ID is:

- 1st Gen

  - iPhone 5S
  - iPhone SE (1st generation)
  - iPhone 6
  - iPhone 6 Plus
  - iPad mini 3
  - iPad (2017)
  - iPad (2018)
  - iPad (2019)
- 2nd Gen

  - iPhone 6S
  - iPhone 6S Plus
  - iPhone 7
  - iPhone 7 Plus
  - iPhone 8
  - iPhone 8 Plus
  - iPhone SE (2nd generation)
  - iPad Pro 12.9-inch (1st generation)
  - iPad Pro 9.7-inch
  - iPad Pro 12.9-inch (2nd generation)
  - iPad Pro 10.5-inch
  - iPad Air 2
  - iPad Air (3rd generation)
  - iPad mini 4
  - iPad mini (5th generation)
  - MacBook Air (2018)
  - MacBook Pro